# Как объединить вывод с трех таблиц в одну

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, выборка

Я создал базу данных и не могу объединить три столбца в один.

Вот, что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
SELECT 
   [Purchases].[PurchaseID], [Purchases].[UserID],
   [Purchases].[ItemID],
   [Users].[Age], [Items].[Price], [Date]
FROM [Purchases], [Users], [Items]
```

Результат:
[image: Результат работы первого скрипта]

А если все вместе выбрать:

```
SELECT * FROM [Purchases], [Users], [Items]
```

Результат:

[image: Результат работы второго скрипта]

Если кратко, то я хочу объединить все три таблицы в одну по IDшникам, а не иметь множество разных вариаций их объединения.

Диаграмма БД:

[image: Диаграмма БД]

Comment: почитайте про sql JOIN

Comment: Прочитал переписал запрос, но все равно выводит не как я хотел, но таблицы объединил. 
{SELECT * FROM [Purchases]
INNER JOIN [Users] ON [Users].[UserID] = [Purchases].[UserID]
INNER JOIN [Items] ON [Items].[ItemID] = [Purchases].[ItemID]}   Теперь выводит данные так, как я хотел, но в формате **PurchaseID | UserID | ItemID | Date | UserID | Age | ItemID | Price**, как убрать повторяющиеся столбцы?

Comment: Никогда не используйте `*`.